# Downloading file with Express

Tags: ajax, node.js, express

I'm using Express and I need to download a file from server. I can easily download it with just `<a href="mylink"></a>`, but there is some query parameters, that I want to hide from user.

So now I'm trying to use jQuery.ajax that sending a request to Express (srv1) and then Express sending request with my parameters to the another server (srv2). Server responds me with 'Content-disposition' header and a file data. It's ok. And there is a question - can I use that file and respond with it to my initial ajax request?

The problem is, that even `res.download()` with files (that already on my srv1) doesn't work. Express sets headers well, but no file is prompting to download. Maybe there is a probem in ajax?

Comment: Show the code where you fetch data from s2 on s1 and what you have tried to send to client.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot cause the browser to perform a file download with a javascript ajax request (this is a security limitation). See https://stackoverflow.com/a/9970672/266795 for details. You'll need a normal browser GET or POST request to get a proper file save dialog.

Comment: Thanks for answer. I'll get rid of ajax. Request from the browser to node works!

Comment: hey can you add a sample code, i'm also lookiking for the same