# Why won't my file download with nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, download

I send a xmlhttprequest from a webpage to the nodejs router like so:

```
var name = $(this).find('td:eq(0)').html();
        var docNum = $('#docNum').val();
        //alert("fileName=" + name + "&docNum=" + docNum);
        xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {
                isUnique = xhttp.responseText;
                if(isUnique == "false"){
                    alert("ID is not unique please pick another document ID ");
                }else{
                    $("form#docForm").submit();
                }
            }
        };
        xhttp.open("POST", "/downloadDocument", true);
        xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        var params = "fileName=" + name + "&docNum=" + docNum;
        xhttp.send(params);
```

And this works fine, the request gets to the router and the router is able to read both the variables properly.

This is the part of the router code that doesn't work properly:

```
router.post("/downloadDocument", function(req, res){
        var doc = req.body.docNum;
        var fileName = req.body.fileName;
        var document = Document.findOne({Name: fileName, Dossier: doc}, function(err, obj){
            var path = obj.Name;
            console.log(path);
            fs.writeFile(obj.Name, obj.File);
            res.download("./" + obj.Name);
        });
    });
```

And all it does is redirect me to a previous page, it doesn't download the file, even though the file exists, and i have no idea why.

I've also tried using

```
  var filestream = fs.createReadStream(obj.File);
  filestream.pipe(res);
```

Instead of res.download

Here is the console output for this request:

```
Apples.jpg
POST /downloadDocument 200 4.814 ms - -
POST /dossierEdit 302 12.898 ms - 62 #This part concerns me and redirects me while i do not ask for this page in my code
GET /dossiers 304 20.793 ms - -
GET /public/stylesheets/css/bootstrap.min.css 304 2.737 ms - -
GET /public/stylesheets/css/simple-sidebar.css 304 2.921 ms - -
GET /public/stylesheets/style.css 304 2.327 ms - -
GET /public/stylesheets/css/font-awesome.min.css 404 3.502 ms - 56
GET /public/css/style.css 404 1.097 ms - 33
GET /public/stylesheets/css/font-awesome.min.css 404 0.492 ms - 56
GET /public/css/style.css 404 1.107 ms - 33
```

Just to clarify, my goal is to have the file sent to the client, not saved to the server.

Comment: is the callback function of Document.findOne() executed? do you see the path in the log? (due to console.log(path) )

Comment: Yes the callback is executed and i see the path, which it displays as just the filename that i put in, i also get an console error if i try to download a file that does not exist

Comment: The findOne is a mongoDB request using Mongoose, i store the files in a mongo database, request the one i want to download using the findOne function, then create a local file using fs.writeFile(which works since i see the files appear locally, and i can open them) and now what i try to do is download them, which is not working.

Comment: Just to clarify, my goal is to have the file sent to the client, not saved to the server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe there are a couple of issues.

1. [Files cannot be downloaded via an ajax call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18723758/downloading-file-with-express).
2. The `fs.writeFile(obj.Name, obj.File)` call is asynchronous, so even if (1) wasn't an issue, the file would likely not be
   present when `res.download("./" + obj.Name)` would be called. Use `fs.writeFileSync` instead.
3. You are likely getting redirected to the previous page because of the `$("form#docForm").submit()` call that happens when the ajax call returns, which submits a form to some other page.

To resolve your issue, try submitting an actual form with post data to the "`/downloadDocument`" endpoint instead of doing an ajax call.

I hope that helps.

Comment: I now use $,post from jquery to send a post request, which works, and it sends the data back to the page, i can print it with the callback function, but its not downloading a file, it's just streaming data back, im now using createReadStream and filestream.pipe(res) to send the data back. Any idea on how to fix this?

Comment: I'm guessing that just doing a regular post is not an option, here? Take a look at [download.js](http://danml.com/download.html), with it, you can create a blob from the data you are sending back and download it on the client site. It doesn't work in older browsers, so consider other options if you need more browser support.

Comment: I can try a regular post but that would require a unnecessary hidden form which i think is rather ugly and hard to do since im making table row clickable to download the files, but first i will check out the download.js, thanks for your help, it helped me a lot :)

Comment: This solved it, used jquery to append the page with a form and just a regular post submit of that form, thank you very much :D